# Issue while updating the table field using Ormlite Android

Tags: android, ormlite

I am new to Ormlite, I am trying to update a field in table. 
In ormlite_config file I have it as

```
fieldName=customerAddress1
```

In model class it is declared as,

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
private String customerAddress1;
```

The code for update which I have written is,

```
UpdateBuilder<Customer, Integer> updateBuilder = customerDao.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue( "customerAddress1", address );
updateBuilder.where().eq( "id", id );
```

I want the record to be updated by the 'id' provided so applied where condition accordingly.
The address is not updated also there is no exception thrown, so what can be the issue?

Comment: Did you actually call `.update()` on your `updateBuilder`?  What number was returned by the method?  Can you turn on logging to see what SQL was done?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to call update() method after updating values. They only it
>   will works.

```
UpdateBuilder<Customer, Integer> updateBuilder = customerDao.updateBuilder();

updateBuilder.updateColumnValue( "customerAddress1", address );

updateBuilder.where().eq( "id", id );

updateBuilder.update();
```